# POST is not getting through to web service

Tags: ajax, jquery, autocomplete, asmx, jquery-1.8

I've added my code to pastebin at the following address:
http://pastebin.com/L03zGPhS
The service is up and running.
I can invoke it.  I am additionally using firebug and getting the following results on the POST:

```
POST http://localhost:51204/AddrService.asmx/GetZipCode
15ms    
HeadersPostResponse
JSON
zip
"40"
Source
{'zip': '40' }
```

Showing the service function:

```
  [WebMethod]
  public List<Zip> GetZipCode(string zip)
```

I can get this to work with jQuery 1.4.2, but I'm upgrading a lot of jQuery widgets to 1.8 and can't get the autocomplete to work.  Am I missing something they changed in the AJAX autocomplete call.  Documentation to a correct answer will suffice if it is useful.

UPDATE I found through Google Chrome that I'm getting a 500 error.  I'm not certain why because I'm hitting localhost on both the service and the aspx page.  Does anybody know if they changed something that would affect the security of hitting localhost, or if I could have possibly left out and important jQuery reference that would let autocomplete work for 1.4 but not 1.8?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work ? Do the alert() calls trigger or not in your example ?

Comment: Both of the alert calls trigger.  The first one triggers on the error and simply states error=undefined.  The second triggers when it completes.  The Ajax never posts to the web service.  I have a break point on it, and it never triggers.

Comment: Someone experienced with stack overflow please mark this as too specific and unanswered.  I've decided to go with the <ajaxToolkit autocomplete> because I knew I could get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this sheds light on your problem — the autocomplete API states that :

> "You must always call the response callback even if you encounter an
>   error. This ensures that the widget always has the correct state."

(source : http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I had a response in, but I removed it because it kept telling me it was unable to get the value of the property 'length': object is null or undefined.  I figured this was because it wasn't getting to the service and the response would then be null and couldn't be mapped to a value. If you think this is not the case please respond. My response was:
    response($.map(data.d, function (item) {return {
                             // POPULATE JSON OBJECTS WITH XML ITEMS RETURNED BY WEBMETHOD FOR JS MANIPULATION
value: item.theZip} }));